# How to check for presence of the google earth plugin using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-plugin

How can I determine whether the Google Earth Plugin is installed in the browser using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`isInstalled`](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/google_earth_namespace#a246b165f799202509fb93fa821872a87) method:

```
google.load("earth", "1");
if(google.earth.isInstalled()) {
    //Installed!
}
```

However, note that if the plugin is not installed, the user will be automatically prompted to download it. So this is only really of use if you want to only display certain content to users who already have the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I tried this code and it generates a JavaScript error: **TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'load'**. I think there is probably some up-front init code, so I am going to look around and see if I can figure out what I am missing...

Comment: You're right about the additional code - you'll need to include `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>` first.

Comment: Oh, and the download prompt will only appear if you attempt to initialize a plugin instance (`google.earth.createInstance()`) - so you can use `isInstalled()` first to decided whether you want to initialize, based on whether the plugin is installed.

Comment: i have tried this but it is not working for me. i can load google earth in the browser but the is installed check does not work